# Sum-of-products simplification

Tags: logic

I have the sum of products expression

(X1 && ~X2 && ~X3) || (X1 && X2 && X4) || (X1 && ~X2 && X3 && ~X4)

and I am supposed to simplify it to its minimum expression.

I have it simplified to  (X1 && ~X2 && ~X3) || (X1 && X2 && X4) || (X1 && ~X2 && ~X4).

Shouldn't (X1 && X2 && X4) || (X1 && ~X2 && ~X4) go to X1 || 1 meaning the whole expression would just be X1? The truth tables don't match up and I found an online karnaugh map that says it would just be what I have it simplified to, but I don't understand why the X2 and X4 don't cancel out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: No.  To see whether such guesses are correct, you can try using a truth table.

Comment: I have to show the simplification algebraically but I know the truth table of the simplified expression does match that of the original but why can't you simplify any further? If I were to distribute, then it would be X1(~X2&&~X3 || X2&&X4 || ~X2&&~X4) (?)
Which then would mean X1(~X2&&~X3 || 1) = X1? I have to be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does (X1 && X2 && X4) || (X1 && ~X2 && ~X4) go to X1 || 1 ??

Try this line of the truth table...
$$
X1=1
\\
X2=1
\\
X4=0
$$
The point is that X2 && X4 is not the negation of ~X2 && ~X4

Comment: Ahhh okay! I was misinterpreting the rule (x&&y || x&&~y) = x (where x = x1 and y = x2&&x4). 
~y would mean ~(x2&&x4) which results to (~x2 || ~x4) not (x2&&x4).  
Thank you so much for your help!